# O que é o Spectre?

Tags: terminologia, segurança

O **Spectre** é uma falha de segurança que compromete uma grande quantidade de sistemas.

- O que é?
- Como ele funciona?
- Que tipo de sistemas e dispositivos estão vulneráveis?
- O que pode ser feito para se defender dele?
- Por que ele recebeu esse nome?

Comment: Os votos de fechamento estão considerando que a pergunta é sobre hardware? Eu acho válida, especialmente considerando a relevância dessa vulnerabilidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que quem votou para fechar não deve ter entendido a pergunta.

Comment: Eu uso o Iobit ASC e ele faz o patch no Windows 10 para correção.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## O que é?

O **Spectre** é uma vulnerabilidade decorrente de uma falha de projetos de microprocessadores que permitem que processos maliciosos possam ler a memória pertencentes a outros processos.

Foi descoberto junto com o **Meltdown** em meados de 2017, mas tornou-se público apenas na primeira semana de 2018.

## Como ele funciona?

Para entender como o **Spectre** funciona, é necessário entrar-se em alguns detalhes de arquitetura de computadores, em especial o *pipeline*, a execução especulativa, o *branch prediction* e a memória cache.

#### O que é *pipeline*?

Para um processador executar uma instrução, é necessário realizar-se várias ações:

- Buscar a instrução a ser executada na memória.
- Decodificar a instrução e identificá-la.
- Mapear os registradores que a instrução referência.
- Executar a instrução propriamente.
- Armazenar o resultado da instrução em algum registrador.

Os passos exatos obviamente variam bastante de um tipo de processador para outro. Processadores antigos executam uma instrução por vez, o que significa que apenas uma das etapas acima estaria ativa em um determinado momento. Processadores mais novos têm ganho de desempenho ao implementar o conceito de pipeline, onde uma instrução inicia a sua execução antes da anterior terminar: Enquanto o resultado da instrução `X` está sendo armazenada em algum registrador, a instrução `X+1` já está sendo executada, a instrução `X+2` está tendo os registradores mapeados, a instrução `X+3` está sendo decodificada e a `X+4` está sendo buscada na memória.

No entanto, o *pipeline* tem dois problemas:

- Quando ocorrem instruções de desvio condicionais do tipo `se A então B, senão C`, pois antes da instrução que avalia `A` ter o seu resultado conhecido as instruções consecutivas já estão entrando *pipeline*. O processador não tem como saber se ele vai colocar o caminho do `então` ou o caminho do `senão` no *pipeline*.
- Quando o resultado de uma instrução depende de carregar da memória principal algum valor qualquer, especialmente se este valor não estiver presente na memória cache. Carregar um valor da memória principal para um registrador pode demorar algumas centenas de ciclos do processador.

E é aí que entra a execução especulativa.

#### O que é execução especulativa?

Com a execução especulativa, o processador irá **chutar** o resultado de desvio condicional e então escolher um dos dois caminhos para colocar no *pipeline* mesmo sem saber se era o caminho certo. Se ele tiver acertado, então ótimo, o ganho de desempenho será satisfatório. Se tiver escolhido o caminho errado, ele descarta qualquer alteração que teria resultado disso, volta e toma o outro caminho, o que é mais lento.

Algo similar acontece quando um valor é lido da memória e está indisponível. Para não parar o *pipeline*, o processador chuta um valor lido (normalmente zero) e continua a execução especulativamente com esse valor. Se quando o valor tornar-se disponível, esse revelar-se ser diferente do valor chutado, o processador desfaz as alterações realizadas com o valor especulado e refaz com o valor correto.

#### O que é *branch prediction*?

Para saber é o melhor lado para ser chutado em desvios condicionais, o processador utiliza um algoritmo de *branch prediction*.

O *branch prediction* faz uma análise simples no histórico de cada desvio condicional para tentar determinar qual é o melhor lado para chutar. Se um determinado `if` tem caído muito mais vezes recentemente no `então`, o *branch prediction* vai dizer para chutar o `então` porque é provável que esse seja o caso da próxima vez que o `if` for executado. O mesmo ocorre se ele estiver caindo muito mais no `senão`. Os detalhes do algoritmo de *branch prediction*, tais como o número necessário de chutes errados para ele mudar de ideia, quais são os desvios que devem ser rastreados e quando variam de processador para processador.

Na prática, `if`s cujo resultado sejam complemente aleatórios e caóticos são raros, então, exceto se o `if` estiver sendo executado pela primeira vez, o *branch prediction* provavelmente vai chutar o lado certo para o processador colocar dentro do *pipeline*.

#### O que é memória cache?

Além da memória principal, existe uma outra memória menor dentro do processador denominada cache. O acesso a ela é bem mais rápido do que o acesso a memória principal, porém a capacidade dela é bem menor. São mantidos na cache os dados mais frequentemente e recentemente acessados da memória principal. Os dados na cache constituem-se em blocos mapeados para a memória principal. O tamanho de cada bloco varia de processador para processador, mas tamanhos como 128, 256 ou 512 bytes são comuns. O tamanho da cache de cada processador é fixo e não pode ser alterado.

Ao manter os dados mais frequentemente e recentemente acessados na cache, evita-se o custo de tempo de ter que localizá-los na memória principal. Como a cache é menor que a memória principal, quando um bloco de dados tem que ser trazido da memória principal para a cache, um outro bloco de dados já existente na cache tem que ser retirado.

Na verdade, processadores modernos mantêm vários níveis de cache, onde além da cache da memória principal, temos a cache da cache e até mesmo a cache da cache da cache. Essas diversas caches são denominadas L1, L2 e L3, onde a L1 é a mais interna. Em processadores Intel, cada núcleo (*core*) do processador tem a sua própria L1 e L2, enquanto que a L3 é compartilhada entre todos os núcleos.

#### Qual é o problema da execução especulativa?

O caminho ou o valor que o processador de fato escolheu (*branch prediction*) para colocar no *pipeline* deveria ser algo completamente invisível para o processo que está sendo executado. Entretanto, dado o fato de que se o processador escolher o lado certo ou o valor certo na execução especulativa, ele executará a tarefa mais rápido do que se escolher o lado ou o valor errado, então o tempo demorado pode ser medido para determinar-se qual caminho o processador executou especulativamente.

A execução especulativa pode trazer blocos da memória principal para a cache do processador. Embora os efeitos da execução especulativa quando incorretos sejam revertidos, não há reversão nas caches. Um bloco de memória trazido à cache devido a uma execução especulativa fica lá mesmo se essa execução especulativa for revertida.

Isso significa que um hacker atacante pode, ao medir o tempo que uma função demora para executar, determinar se ela acessou a cache ou não, mesmo que de forma especulativa. Com certa engenhosidade, é possível fazer com que a diferença entre ter executado de forma rápida e ter executado de forma lenta sirva para revelar o conteúdo de alguma informação existente na memória.

#### Como o **Spectre** pode ser usado para elaborar um ataque?

O **Spectre** é uma vulnerabilidade que permite a um processo malicioso ler (de uma forma bastante indireta) o conteúdo da memória de um outro processo que deveria ser inacessível, ao aproveitar-se da execução especulativa.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que o processo a ser atacado tenha uma verificação como essa em C ([código fornecido pelos descobridores do **Spectre**](https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf)):

```c
if (x < array1_size)
    y = array2[array1[x] * 256];
```

Nesse caso, isso trata-se de um `if` que verifica se o `array1` pode ser acessado. Em caso positivo, o mesmo é acessado e o valor dele lido é usado para indexar-se o `array2`. O atacante precisa ter o controle do valor de `x`. O 256 é um valor que seja grande o suficiente para que diferentes valores de `array1[x]` resultem em diferentes porções de `array2` sendo colocados na cache.

Com isso, o atacante primeiro treina o processador para que a execução especulativa sempre chute que o `if` vai entrar (ou seja, que não cairia em um `else`). Uma forma de fazer isso é atribuir zero para `x` e então invocar o código que contém o `if` acima algumas vezes.

Tendo o processador sido treinado, o atacante realiza algumas operações para garantir que `array1_size` e `array2` fiquem fora da cache. Uma forma de fazer isso é usar a instrução `clflush` que serve especificamente para limpar a cache. Caso isso não seja possível, pode-se acessar diversas partes da memória distantes umas das outras para que elas ocupem a cache e acabem deixando `array1_size` e `array2` fora dela.

O atacante então executa esse código utilizando um valor `x` maior do que `array_size`. Uma vez que `array_size` não está disponível na cache, o processador vai chutar o seu valor e começar uma execução especulativa que vai incorretamente entrar no `if` e fazer uma leitura de dados fora do limite com o `array1[x]`. Como essa leitura é fora do limite, ela resultará em alguma outra informação qualquer que esteja na memória do processo atacado.

Executando-se isso repetidamente com diversos valores para `x`, é possível acessar-se grande parte da memória do programa atacado. Assim sendo se o atacante quiser forçar um acesso especulativo ao endereço de memória `y` do programa atacado, sabendo-se que `a` é o endereço de memória de `array1`, computa-se o `x` com `x = y - a`.

Entretanto, embora qualquer byte da memória do programa atacado possa ser lido pelo mesmo ao acessar-se `array1` fora dos seus limites (mesmo que de forma especulativa), isso ainda não permite ao atacante conhecer o seu conteúdo, até porque, de forma direta, ele só obterá o resultado da execução real, que não será relevante. E é aí que o `array2` entra.

O conteúdo lido de `array1[x]` é usado para acessar-se `array2`, de forma que diferentes partes de `array2` entram na cache para diferentes valores obtidos de `array1[x]`. Supondo que a leitura especulativa de `array1[x]` tenha produzido como resultado um número `k`, um acesso a `array2[k * 256]` será rápido, enquanto que um acesso a qualquer outra parte de `array2` será lento.

Se o atacante tiver acesso a `array2`, ele poderá chutar um valor `j` (vamos supor que 42) e acessá-lo na posição `j * 256` e se esse acesso for rápido, então 42 será o valor da posição correspondente a `x`. Caso contrário (se o acesso for lento) o atacante saberá que o valor na posição `y` não é 42, e poderá repetir esse o processo com outros valores de `j` até descobrir qual é o conteúdo do byte `y`.

Caso o atacante não tenha acesso ao `array2`, ainda assim ele pode invocar o código a ser atacado passando um valor válido de `x` e medir o tempo resultante, de forma que se for rápido, deduz-se que o bloco de `array2` estava na cache e isso ajuda a descobrir qual parte de `array2` foi acessada e consequentemente (com uma boa dose de tentativa e erro) qual o valor de `y`.

Tudo isso é possível se o atacante tiver acesso a um código tal como o demonstrado acima. No entanto, vários outros padrões de código que contenham mais de dois caminhos possíveis (`if`s, `switch`es, `while`s) e façam acessos a blocos de memória (arrays, matrizes e assemelhados) podem ser de alguma forma abusados ao mensurar-se o tempo demorado em execuções especulativas. Ou seja, esses padrões de código que podem ser abusados pelo **Spectre** são comuns e abundantes em quase todos os tipos de programas, muitas vezes encontrados até mesmo dentro de bibliotecas padrão que nele são inclusas.

O ataque não se restringe apenas a código de baixo nível que interaja diretamente com a memória. Por exemplo, o [seguinte ataque em Javascript foi publicado pelos descobridores do **Spectre**](https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf):

```js
if (index < simpleByteArray.length) {
    index = simpleByteArray[index | 0];
    index = (((index * TABLE1_STRIDE)|0) & (TABLE1_BYTES-1))|0;
    localJunk ^= probeTable[index|0]|0;
}
```

Uma variante do **Spectre** é quando o atacante tem o controle não apenas de determinar se um desvio condicional será ou não executado especulativamente, mas também quando ele tem o controle de para onde o desvio ocorre. Em muitas linguagens, isso é mais ou menos o caso que ocorre quando o atacante está se aproveitando de uma função, procedimento ou método que recebe como parâmetro um lambda, um *callback*, uma outra função ou coisa semelhante e essa seja algo que o atacante controle. Dessa forma, a função atacada acaba por executar código escolhido pelo atacante de forma especulativa, aumentando as possibilidades de realizar-se o ataque.

Ataques que determinem um bit de cada vez são possíveis. Isso reduz a necessidade de realizar-se 256 testes por byte da memória atacada para apenas 8 testes por byte (ou seja, 1 por bit).

## Que tipo de sistemas e dispositivos estão vulneráveis?

Quase todos os dispositivos modernos estão vulneráveis. PCs, Notebooks, smartphones, tablets, servidores virtualizados e cloud. Isso ocorre porque quase todos os processadores modernos usam execução especulativa.

Os únicos dispositivos que ficam de fora são microcontroladores, arduino, dispositivos embarcados, calculadoras e outros dispositivos que têm projetos extremamente simples e capacidades extremamente limitadas ou que são bastante antigos. Esses dispositivos não usam execução especulativa ou mesmo *pipelines* em seus processadores.

Especificamente, o programa atacante precisa ter a possibilidade de interagir de alguma forma com o programa a ser atacado, o que diminui bastante a possibilidade de um hacker aproveitar-se disso. No entanto, no caso de navegadores, isso é bem mais factível de ocorrer vez que o Javascript permite ao atacante forjar o código que acesse qualquer outra parte da memória do navegador de forma especulativa (inclusive a pertencente a outras abas), o que em teoria significa que qualquer aba poderia usar o **Spectre** para ler o conteúdo de qualquer outra aba ou mesmo o de detalhes internos do navegador, e com isso roubar senhas ou outros tipos de informações sensíveis.

## O que pode ser feito para se defender dele?

O **Spectre** é algo muito difícil de se defender. As duas formas de combatê-lo são:

- Eliminar ou modificar bastante o funcionamento da execução especulativa.
- Eliminar-se a possibilidade de medir-se o tempo de forma precisa o suficiente para viabilizar o ataque.

Nenhuma das duas alternativas é muito atraente. A execução especulativa é que traz altos ganhos de desempenho, não podendo ser abandonada. E mesmo que fosse, ainda iria demandar a troca de todos os processadores de quase todos os PCs, notebooks, tablets, smartphones e servidores produzidos nos últimos 20 anos ou mais, o que claramente é inviável.

Os desenvolvedores de navegadores (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, etc) por enquanto estão fornecendo uma solução paliativa que consiste em atualizações que reduzem a precisão das funções no Javascript que medem o tempo. Com isso, a ideia é impedir que um atacante possa medir o tempo que determinadas instruções demoraram para executar, o que impede o ataque de surtir efeito.

É de se admitir que essa solução é bastante paliativa e simplória, mas uma vez que essa falha veio ao público apenas muito recentemente, ainda desconhecem-se outros métodos que permitam a sua mitigação.

Os desenvolvedores da LLVM estão modificando a forma como ocorre a compilação de código para reduzir (mas isso não elimina ainda) a possibilidade de acessar-se partes indevidas da memória por meio de execução especulativa.

## Por que ele recebeu esse nome?

A chave de tudo está na execução especulativa. A palavra *especulativo* lembra *espectro*. Além disso, nas palavras dos descobridores, esse problema é algo que irá **assombrar** a todos por muitos anos, pois é algo bastante difícil de ser corrigido. E é por isso que ele recebeu esse logotipo:

[image]

Eu ainda acrescentaria que execuções especulativas de código que são revertidas é algo que me soa como um código "fantasma" ter sido executado no processador. Ele é algo que deveria ser totalmente invisível e indetectável e que não deixaria nenhum traço perceptível de sua existência no mundo real tal como se nunca tivesse existido, até porque dependia de condições que não eram verdadeiras para vir a existir de fato. Mas, algum efeito paranormal da sua (não-)existência ainda assim é capaz de fazer com que de alguma forma ele se manifeste no mundo dos vivos trazendo assombração e tormento.

## Referências

- https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com.br/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html
- https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf
- https://spectreattack.com/
- http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20180101/513630.html
- https://winaero.com/blog/windows-7-8-1-fixes-meltdown-spectre-cpu-flaws/
- https://winaero.com/blog/secure-chrome-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabilities/